# Creating table schema with pre-defined keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a table schema that needs to be optimized well, the reason for this being tables that will have 3 to 5 million records. The big concern here is with regard to search, in this case the famous LIKE %% ... is not an option, to avoid this, at the time of each insertion, 3 key words will be created based on the main field as a name of something , example:

Fictitious table "cities" with the following columns

```
id | name | visibility | key_1 | key_2 | key_3
```

So let's enter the city of New York as a record, in this case we will have two words.

```
key_1 = new
key_2 = york
```

In that way, a search in a table with millions of records would look like this:

```
select name from cities
    where visibility = 1
        and(
            key_1 = 'new' or
            key_1 = 'york' or
            key_2 = 'new' or
            key_2 = 'york'
        );
```

The question is: will it even be faster than Full text or wildcards LIKE %%? Is it a good practice?

I have seen large companies using this technique, however, I would like your opinion.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh thank you, I am not speak english very well

Answer (score 1):

Minor correction in the query:

```
select name from cities
    where visibility = 1
        and 'new' in (key1, key2) 
and 'york' in  (key1, key2) ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but what do you think about this way, is good for search performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you want performance, you want a table called `CityKeys`, with one row per city and one per key.

Then you can write the query as:

```
select c.name
from cities c
where c.visibility = 1 and
      exists (select 1 from citykeys ck where ck.cityid = c.cityid and ck.key = 'new') and
      exists (select 1 from citykeys ck where ck.cityid = c.cityid and ck.key = 'york') ;
```

If the ordering of the keys matters, then you can include a `keynumber` column into the logic.

This can then take advantage of an index on `citykeys(cityid, key)`.